# Edit EXIF data (owner) based on another field (camera model)

Tags: windows, photos, exif, copyright

I would like to edit the EXIF data on a large set of JPEGs (about 1500) to include the name of the photographer/copyright owner. I know that there are tools to do that in batch, however the trick is that my photos were taken by different people (using different cameras).

Is there a tool/program, which will let me specify which owner to associate with a particular camera and then batch edit my files? Or more simply, just edit the EXIF owner field only if the camera model field equals a given value?

Solutions working on Windows 7 would be great, but I could also copy the files to my server and do it under Linux if that's the only option...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Lightroom 4 (and probably earlier versions as well).

1. In the Library module, load up all the photos.
2. In the Library Filter bar, choose Text.
3. Filter by EXIF: searchable fields include Make, Model, and Serial Number of the camera used.
4. Highlight the filtered results and add copyright info in the metadata section.
5. Repeat for each owner/camera

reference: [Find photos using the Library Filter bar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WSAB7B303E-081D-4617-BF47-B4B8D3D49CC3.html)

There is a free 30-day trial of Lightroom at the Adobe Web site.